# PHP Spanish Character using print_r

Tags: php, character-encoding

Hi I am printing this information:

```
preg_match_all($pattern2, $row['introtext'], $arr2, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r($arr2[text][0]);
```

But I get this:

> Este curso se enfoca en proporcionar las habilidades y conocimientos necesarios para instalar, operar y localizar fallas en una red empresarial peque�a de sucursal, incluyendo configurar un conmutador, un enrutador y conectar a una WAN e implementar la seguridad de la red. El Participante debe poder completar la configuraci�n e implementaci�n de una peque�a red de oficina sucursal con supervisi�n.

As you can see I have a strange character for spanish letters.

I tried with

```
html_entity_decode
```

and

```
utf8_decode()
```

but those do not work.

Does anybody have a suggestion for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Fyi, you should quote array keys: `$arr2['text'][0]`

Comment: I'm guessing this is going to be another case for `<?php header('Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8'); ?>`

Comment: You need to output appropriate char-set headers, e.g. `Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`, otherwise the browser has no idea WHAT character set you're sending over.

Comment: either the header or utf8_encode

Comment: I tried this one too, and it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The problem is usually two-fold, and not related to PHP. In order for international characters to properly work, you need

- Your file to be encoded in UTF-8 (without BOM)
- To have a `<meta>` tag that says the page is encoded in UTF-8.

The first one depends on your text editor. If you told us what you are using we could help you find out how to put your files in UTF-8. Otherwise, you could always Google it.

The second one is easy to fix. Just add the correct `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` of your document. For example, in HTML5, it's:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Now, if you can't, for some reason, use those solutions, you could always try and call [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on the text you wish to print. That could work.

Comment: @Xeon06 *"Otherwise, you could always Google it."* lol what is this "Google" you speak of? You mean people could Google their problems and not have other people do it for them?!?! Where has this been all my life?

Comment: @Jean well it's hard to see what's wrong from here. Perhaps you could reproduce your problem on a small scale and upload a file for us to look at?

Comment: @rdlowrey Yeah I hear it's pretty nifty. Wouldn't know myself.

Answer (score 1):

`html_entity_decode` does not work because it converts html entities (&*entity*;) in the string to their equivalent in UTF-8 (by default) or some other character set. But your problem is that the browser doesn't recognize this character set and outputs question marks.

For an excellent explanation, read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

To improve your question it will help if you tell what the character encoding of your data in your database is (where it seems to come from judging by the code).

Answer (score 0):

A suggested improvement to the original question:
If your text output is from only one file, or a database, then the already suggested solutions are fine. If you are accessing sources that do not handle character encoding, you are forced to use e.g. `iconv("LATIN1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $var)` to make use of such strings in your code. That's when you're in trouble with print_r() or var_dump() and so on. That doesn't really show in your question, but it is nevertheless a challenge, which I have to put up with quite often, but I have no solution to it.